# How to remove from list with onclick function?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I am trying to create a function that will allow me to remove an item from the shopping cart of the site I'm working on. I want the last image when clicked to remove that specific item from the list and immediately show it. I don't want to have to refresh the page to see the update. I have tried everything I can find, and tried to kind of reverse engineer my addtocart one from before but I just can't get it. Any help is appreciated!

```
var x = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingList'));

document.write('<table align="center" >');
    document.write('<tr>');
    document.write('<th>' + " " + '</th>');
    document.write('<th>' + "Product" + '</th>');
    document.write('<th>' + "Price" + '</th>');
    document.write('<th>' + "Quantity" + '</th>');
    document.write('<th>' + "Remove" + '</th>');
    document.write('</tr>');
        for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            document.write('<tr>');
            for(var j = 0; j < 1; j++){
                document.write('<td align="center">');
                document.write('<img src="');           
                document.write(x[i].itemImageSrc);
                document.writeln('"style="height:100px; width:150px;"/>');  
                document.write('</td>');    
                document.writeln('<td align="center">' + x[i].itemDescription + '</td>');
                document.writeln('<td align="center">' + x[i].itemPrice + '</td>');
                document.write('<td align="center">' + "1" + '</td>');
                document.write('<td align="center">');
                document.write('<img id="can_'+i+'" onclick="removeItem(i)" src="');            
                document.write("./images/Icons/garbagecan.png");
                document.writeln('"style="height:25px; width:20px;"/>');    
                document.write('</td>');
            }
            document.write('</tr>');
        }
    document.write('</table>');


function removeItem(i) {
    var list = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("shoppingList"));
    list.pop(document.getElementById("can_'+i+'"));
    //x[i] = null;
}
```

Comment: [1] When you are clearing the cart, you are modifying a temporary variable and not the actual session storage, you can change this by updating the session storage.
[2] While populating the cart, you are using a temporary variable, so its value is not updated even if the session storage value is changed. You will have to look for an alternate implementation for this.

Comment: this one `'<img id="can_'+i+'" onclick="removeItem(i)" src="'` should be `'<img id="can_'+i+'" onclick="removeItem('+i+')" src="'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TheChetan was kind of right. What I need to do was add

```
sessionStorage.setItem("shoppingList", JSON.stringify(list));
    window.location.href=window.location.href
```

to the end of my removeItem function